# Can not connect to instance of SQL Server that is running in Docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker

I've downloaded and ran this Docker image `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`:

```
docker run -d -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Password!1" -p 1433:1433 --name sqlserver-test -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
```

up this point everything is OK.

Then I go to the SQL Server Management Studio and try to connect to `localhost` with user `sa`, but something is wrong because SSMS throws an exception that says something about network error.

Any ideas?

Comment: try connecting to `localhost, 1433` Also, confirm you don't have a real install of SQL Server on your machine trying to use 1433. You might need to map port 1434->1433 and then connect with `localhost, 1434`

Comment: Tanks @dfundako, that was. I mapped ports 1434->1433 and the error disappeared. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try connecting to `localhost, 1433` Also, confirm you don't have a real install of SQL Server on your machine trying to use port 1433. You might need to map port 1434->1433 and then connect with `localhost, 1434`